# Using Multiple Submit Buttons to Delete and Modify

Tags: php

I have an issue where I need to be able to use check boxes in order to delete and modify data in a mysql database.

What is the most efficient way of being able to use multiple submit buttons to either insert data based on what the user types into the text boxes, delete based on the check boxes selected, and modify based on the check boxes selected.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 <?php 
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$dbName     = "ticket_history";
$table_name = "ticket_history";

################ Connect to the Database and SELECT DATA ####################################
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = "SELECT Auto,Date,Ticket_Number,Description,Result FROM $table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
#############################################################################################
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<table width=50%>
    <form method="post">
        <table width border='0'>
            <tr><td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date:<input type="text" name="date"/></td>
            <td>Ticket #:<input type="text" name="ticket"/></td></tr>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Description:<TEXTAREA COLS=50 name="description"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Result     :<TEXTAREA COLS=50 name="result"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
            </table>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="create" value="Add"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="modify" value="Modify"/></td></tr>
        </table>    
</table>

<?php
print "<table width=80% border=1>\n"; 
$cols = 0; 
while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$id = $get_info['Auto'];
if($cols == 0) 
{ 
  $cols = 1; 
  print "<tr>";
  print "<th>Select</th>";  
  foreach($get_info as $col => $value) 
  { 
    print "<th>$col</th>"; 
  } 
  print "<tr>\n"; 
} 
print "<tr>\n"; 
print "<td><input type='checkbox' name='selected[]' id='checkbox[]' value=$id></td>";
foreach ($get_info as $field) 
print "\t<td align='center'><font face=arial size=1/>$field</font></td>\n"; 
print "</tr>\n"; 
} 
print "</table>\n"; 

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO ticket_history (Date, Ticket_Number, Description, Result) 
                 VALUES ('$_POST[date]', '$_POST[ticket]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[result]')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert);
if ($result_insert) {
echo "win";
}
else {
echo "fail";
}

}
elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $ids = array();
foreach($_POST['selected'] as $selected) {
    if (ctype_digit($selected)) {
        $ids[] = $selected;
    }
    else {
        die('invalid input');
    }
$sql_delete = sprintf('DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN (%s)', 
    implode(',', $ids));

$result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete);
}
if ($result_delete) {
echo $result_delete;
}
else {
echo "fail";
}
}
elseif (isset($_POST['modify'])) {
    header('Location: modify_ticket.php');
}



mysql_close($conn);
?>
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>

Insert.php
<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$dbName     = "ticket_history";
$table_name = "ticket_history";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db($dbName);


$query_insert = "INSERT INTO ticket_history (Date, Ticket_Number, Description, Result) 
                 VALUES ('$_POST[date]', '$_POST[ticket]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[result]')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert);
if ($result_insert) {
echo "win";
}
else {
echo "fail";
}
 #header( 'Location: ticket_history.php' ); 
?>



Delete.php

<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$dbName     = "ticket_history";
$table_name = "ticket_history";

################ Connect to the Database and SELECT DATA ####################################
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = "SELECT Date,Ticket_Number,Description,Result FROM $table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
#####################################

$ids = array();
foreach($_POST['selected'] as $selected) {
    if (ctype_digit($selected)) {
        $ids[] = $selected;
    }
    else {
        die('invalid input');
    }
$sql = sprintf('DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN (%s)', 
    implode(',', $ids));

$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

 header( 'Location: ticket_history.php' ); 

?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the insert and delete code and put it on top of the main file instead of having them into files. the simplest way would be to submit the form to itself and based on the submit button clicked run the code block

```
if($_POST['create']){
  // insert code
}
elseif($_POST['delete']){
  // delete code
}
```

continue the logic of if/else/elseif to handle all the cases. This strikes me as the simplest way to get done what you want to do.

Edit:
Not sure but seems like you are handling the $_POST['create'] etc after the HTML code. You should always do that sort of processing BEFORE the html rendering and even before the query to get the records you want to display, this way your get query will always bring up to date results.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is your submit button's have the same name,

So:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit" />
```

PHP:

```
switch(strtolower($_POST['submit'])){
    case "delete":
    // delete logic
    break;

    case "edit":
    // edit logic
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use multiple submit buttons, you can use PHP to determine which button was pressed. Based on this, you can have your application do different things with the data.

It's not clear what you want to accomplish with multiple buttons. Perhaps you could give more detail.

[Edit]

Looking over your code in detail, it is plain to see that it is quickly becoming a maintenance nightmare. Even if your app is tiny and you don't want to code use MVC pattern, you I still recommend using classes and separating **presentation** from application **logic** and from **data** access. Then it's much easier to maintain the application(fix bugs) and make changes.

If you are building anything more than a trivial script, I recommend using one of the excellent PHP frameworks:

- http://framework.zend.com/
- http://www.symfony-project.org/
- http://codeigniter.com/
- http://cakephp.org/
- and many more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$dbName     = "ticket_history";
$table_name = "ticket_history";


################ Connect to the Database and SELECT DATA ####################################
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = "SELECT Auto,Date,Ticket_Number,Description,Result FROM $table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
#############################################################################################

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO ticket_history (Date, Ticket_Number, Description, Result) 
                     VALUES ('$_POST[date]', '$_POST[ticket]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[result]')";
    $result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert);
    if ($result_insert) {
        echo "win";
    }
    else {
        echo "fail";
    }

}
elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $ids = array();
    foreach($_POST['selected'] as $selected) {
        if (ctype_digit($selected)) {
            $ids[] = $selected;
        }
        else {
            die('invalid input');
        }
    $sql_delete = sprintf('DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN (%s)', 
    implode(',', $ids));

    $result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete);
    }
        if ($result_delete) {
            echo $result_delete;
        }
        else {
            echo "fail";
        }
}
elseif (isset($_POST['modify'])) {
    header('Location: modify_ticket.php');
}


?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<table width=50%>
    <form method="post">
        <table width border='0'>
            <tr><td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date:<input type="text" name="date"/></td>
            <td>Ticket #:<input type="text" name="ticket"/></td></tr>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Description:<TEXTAREA COLS=50 name="description"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Result     :<TEXTAREA COLS=50 name="result"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
            </table>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="create" value="Add"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="modify" value="Modify"/></td></tr>
        </table>    
</table>
```

I modified the code a little bit and THIS WILL WORK; however, it only works on the SECOND click.

When I select something and click DELETE, it will not delete, but when I do it again it will

Why is this?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Take the code for deletion and insertion above the select, so that the desired deletion of updation is done before you show the data.